# How to underlay or get transparency to watermark using FPDF2 on python?

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I found his code, but it is overlaying the watermark in my document, actually i would like to underlay it, or get some transparency to my watermark:

```
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=18)
pdf.rotate(45 ,150,140)
pdf.set_text_color(255,235,205)

def create_watermark(input_pdf, output, watermark):
    watermark_obj = PdfFileReader(watermark)
    watermark_page = watermark_obj.getPage(0)

    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(input_pdf)
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

    # Watermark all the pages
    for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
        page = pdf_reader.getPage(page)
        page.mergePage(watermark_page)
        pdf_writer.addPage(page)

    with open(output, 'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)

input_pdf = "Apostila de investimentos.pdf"
output = 'merged.pdf'
watermark = 'RODRIGO ROMÃO.pdf'
create_watermark(input_pdf, output, watermark)
```

Comment: FYI there is a section dedicated to altering PDF documents in fpdf2 documentation: https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/ExistingPDFs.html